# Installing RVM on server with no access to public domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, curl, rvm

I need to install Ruby on Rails on a remote Ubuntu server. I have been following this link for the installation steps - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

One of the commands in it to install RVM is 
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
But my server does not provide access to public domain URLs; how can I overcome this?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

before running `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

run `gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3`

then run `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

then close the current terminal and restart again. Hope it helps!

Comment: @ShravanJKumar, Before installing RVM, you need to import the RVM GPG Key. This command will do that.